There is a divergence between build-in Intellij IDEA 'Commit' tab and git bash
I'm running Intellij IDEA Ultimate on Windows 11 Pro. In my project when I updated the main branch, I see changes in the 'Commit' tab of the IDE, and nothing appears at the git bash when given a command 'git status'. And vice versa, if I rollback the changes in the 'Commit' tab, I see the changes in git bash running 'git status'.
I've tried to reinstall Intellij IDEA, applied updates and also tried to reinstall git bash on my machine. I've tried command 'git clean -fdx', but the issue apparently relates to Intellij IDEA.
Yet nothing worked.
Please help

If you updated (which I guess it means that you pulled), why do you expect something to show up in git status?

Those changes in the Commit tab are local changes and should be visible in the in the git status, too. What happens if you refresh the commit window?

@eftshift0 well, I've pulled using git GUI of Intellij IDEA, and files appeared as "modified".
although they were not. I need to rollback the changes to align them to remote branch and then they appear at the 'git status'

@DinoLetic nothing changes if I refresh

What happens when you do "git status" inside the idea terminal? Are you sure you have the same project opened in git bash?

@DinoLetic, yes, there is no doubts project is the same. I should try idea terminal, good thought

@DinoLetic thanks for an idea, but another terminal doesn't work as well

What do you mean it does not work? Intelij depends on your native terminal. Git status from this terminal will match what intelij shows. Can you compare why your terminal does not show same as the git bash?

@DinoLetic thank you for your attention. I've tried the available terminals inside Intellij (regular Command Prompt, Windows PowerShell, and Git Bash Terminal) all of which show the same 'git status'. The only difference is WSL's Terminal which shows huge output, probably the whole history of changes till I work under the project, don't know why

The solution of the problem is to make a git clone of the project to a new folder and open the fresh version in Intellij IDEA. Apparently, the new project will not have the history of commits within IDE.
